# how to resolve "fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/username/myrepo.git/': Recv failure: Connection was reset"

Tags: github

I am beginner in GitHub when I try to push to GitHub .

I write this code
`git push -u origin main`

then this error is showed up
`fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/username/myrepo.git/': Recv failure: Connection was reset`

I try to connect to another network but same error showed up .
can any one help me please

Comment: Provide detailed steps you have followed to get to this point.